# Windows Mobile and Properties.Settings.Default

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I'm starting on work on my first Windows Mobile 6.5 app in C#, and I'd like to use something similar to the Properties.Settings.Default functionality in standard .Net. Is there an equivalent in Windows Mobile 6.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work-horse class here is System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.  Not available in the Compact Framework.  With the considerable amount of glue needed to support this class, adding it yourself isn't an option either.

The System.Xml namespace contains what you need to serialize your own "settings" object.